# Manipulate factor list in R

Tags: r, vector, apply, lapply

I have a vector in **R** that is a factor list, a list of 256 nfl teams. I need to change every team name from "Washington Redskins" into "WAS" or "New England Patriots" into "NE". What is the best technique for this type of problem. I'm sure this is something easy so don't beat me up on this one.

Comment: My downvote was for the (in my opinion blindingly obvious) confusion regarding why would would be expected to know _a_priori_that "Washington Redskins" should be "WAS" while "New England Patriots" should be "NE". Seems that a more logical expectation would be  for `WR` and `NEP`, i.e the first letters of each name.

Comment: OK let me explain this better, I have a data.frame that is the 2014 schedule with a Hometeam's and AwayTeam's. They are all full team names "Washington Redskins"... So i need to change every HomeTeam & Awayteam to the proper acronym's "WAS"... hopefully that helps explain the problem better

Comment: An explanation (would be nice but you did not address any of the specifics of my complaint), and  .... now let's see some ... code. Code is what SO is all about.

Answer (score 2):

You could read the acronyms from a web page and match the team names against yours.

Here's one example.

```
library(XML)
tab <- readHTMLTable("http://sportsdelve.wordpress.com/abbreviations/")[[1]]
head(tab)
#       V1                     V2
# 1    ARZ      Arizona Cardinals
# 2    ATL        Atlanta Falcons
# 3    BAL       Baltimore Ravens
# 4   BALC        Baltimore Colts
# 5   BCLT Baltimore Colts (1950)
# 6 BALCLT Baltimore Colts (AAFC)
```

And you can use regular expression matching to find your teams...

```
tab[grepl("WAS|NE", tab[[1]]), ]
#     V1                   V2
# 38  NE New England Patriots
# 58 WAS  Washington Redskins
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have a dictionary, i.e. a file with each full name and each short name. You can then match this file to your full names, using the full names as the ID for the match.

Example:

```
full.names <- data.frame(full = c("wash", "wash", "denv", "denv", "wash")) ## needs to be a data frame in order for plyr::join to work

dic <- data.frame(full = c("wash", "denv"), short = c("ww", "dd")) ## the dictionary; one row per unique name

matched <- plyr::join(x = full.names, y = dic, by = "full") ## using join from the plyr package
```

Output:

```
  full short
1 wash    ww
2 wash    ww
3 denv    dd
4 denv    dd
5 wash    ww
```

Comment: This took a little bit of effort but it worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

'merge' command also works: (Using Chaconne's data here)

```
full.names <- data.frame(full = c("wash", "wash", "denv", "denv", "wash")) 
dic <- data.frame(full = c("wash", "denv"), short = c("ww", "dd")) 

merge(full.names,dic)
  full short
1 denv    dd
2 denv    dd
3 wash    ww
4 wash    ww
5 wash    ww
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the levels directly

```
levels(team)
```

will list the order of the levels assigned to your factor

```
levels(team) <- c("ARZ","ATL", ...)
```

will change the labels.